# Wake waiting threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I have 4 threads that are filling concurrently an 50000000x4 matrix. To ensure writes' safety I used an AtomicInteger as pointer. Each iteration each thread copy the pointer value into threadPointer and use it to fill a . 
The first thread that get pointer == buffer.length starts a routine to flush the buffer into memory. The other threads at this point should wait for the the threads to finish its job.
This is my code:

```
if ((threadPointer = pointer.getAndAdd(1)) >= buffer.length ){
    synchronized (flag){
        if(threadPointer == buffer.length){
            sampledSelection();
            pointer.set(0);
            threadPointer = pointer.getAndAdd(1);
            flag.notifyAll();
        }else{
            System.out.println("waiting");
            flag.wait();
            threadPointer = pointer.getAndAdd(1);
            System.out.println("Awaken!");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `notifyAll()` doesn't wake the waiting threads.How can I fix this?

Comment: You aren't using [guarded blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) with your `wait` calls. That allows for a race condition, i.e. if a thread is going to reach the `wait` call but hasn't yet, and another thread calls `notifyAll` too soon, causing it to wait forever.

Comment: I see. I found out that my code had a bug causing unexpected behaviors. One of those caused the thread to call notifyAll() before I expected causing what you wrote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you figured it out but for posterity...

> My problem is that notifyAll doesn't wake the waiting threads. How can I fix this?

Right, you have a classic race condition here.  Let's say 3 threads come and do the `pointer.getAndAdd(1)` around the same time.

1. Thread #1 calls `synchronized (flag)` first and gets into the protected area.
2. Threads #2 and #3 call `synchronized (flag)` but they are locked out until thread #1 unlocks.
3. Thread #1's `pointer` value is equal to the buffer length so it calls `sampledSelection();`, resets the `pointer` to 0, calls `notifyAll()`, and then unlocks.
4. Thread #2 (let's say) now enters the `synchronized` section.  It's `pointer` value is not equal so it goes to `wait()` which unlocks.
5. Thread #3 now enters the `synchronized` section.  It's `pointer` value is not equal so it goes to `wait()` which unlocks.

If no one comes back to call `notifyAll()` then they will wait forever.

As you've figured out, it is important to realize that the only time the `notifyAll()` method works is if the threads are *already waiting*.  Typically what should happen is that the threads should look at condition field to see if they should wait.

Another thing to watch out for is to make sure that the object that you are `synchronized` on is a constant.  In your case `flag` should be defined like:

```
private final Object flag = new Object();
```

If your `flag` can be assigned to another value then the threads will not be locking (or signalizing) on the same object which would cause problems.  Always make sure that you lock on a `final` object.

Hope this helps.